# open and compare autocad files in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, autocad

How can I view and compare AutoCAD files in asp?

I have no idea what to do.

I need to display a project's files to show. But I do not know how we should not do
Dry hard stage is how I compare two files together

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoCAD I/O webservice](https://developer.autodesk.com/api/autocadio/) to open and extract information from DWG files. And use [View & Data](https://developer.autodesk.com/api/view-and-data-api/) to visualize the files on your ASP.NET application. Check this [sample on Github](https://github.com/augustogoncalves/view.and.data-simplest-aspnet/blob/master/FirstViewerWebApp/FirstViewerWebApp/default.aspx).